# Restore and predict tensorflow contrib.learn.DNNRegressor/DNNClassifier without running at least one step of training (which was a missing feature)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following up on the common issue that is mentioned in these threads:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3340
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3306

Currently the way to restore a trained model is: First created a DNNRegressor/DNNClassifier specifying model_dir on constructor, fit() (training step) , and restore it by creating another DNNRegressor/DNNClassifier using the same model_dir in constructor. That works for me and is not the problem.

However, when I want to make the model portable to others, meaning I train on my machine and copy the model file it generates to others, and let them predict on new data sets without training again. It fails.

And from a large and wide search on the issue, I find several resources point out to the same reply: "Right now, there isn't a way to restore and predict without running at least one step of training (which is a missing feature)"

Since this was the reply 3 months ago, and now I'd like to follow up on this to track the feature of restoring without predicting.

Look forward to hearing from experts who develops tensorflow, or any walk-around is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try without with the current version?